# Proving a matrix is PSD

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have been working on Kernels for SVM, so I would like to prove that the matrix \begin{align}
K = \begin{bmatrix}
f\left(x_1, x_1\right) & \cdots & f\left(x_1, x_N\right)\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 
f\left(x_N, x_1\right) & \cdots & f\left(x_N, x_N\right)\\
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{N\times N}
\end{align}

is indeed PSD, where $$f(x,y) = \frac{x \cdot y}{\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}-x \cdot y}, \; \forall x, y\in \mathbb R^n_{>0}.$$

So I want to prove that this holds:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} c_i c_j K_{ij}  \geq  0 $$

for all $c_i, c_j \in \mathbb{R}^N$. I have been trying to found some counterexample, but It seems that this is indeed PSD, however I don't know how to apply the regular methods that I have been thaught.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be a linear function of $A,B$ so it’s not apparent that any matrix would apply. (It does still make sense to ask if $f(A,B)\geq 0.$)

Comment: @Semiclassical I cracked up some thousands of random matrix and the eigvals are always positive

Comment: When $n=2$, that can be verified using $|A\cdot B|\le |A| |B|$. Not sure about general $n$.

Comment: If $A\cdot B$ is "the" scalar product then your $f(A,B)$ is a scalar, not a matrix...

Comment: @Norhther You might want to consider posting this to [stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead, where the users are a bit more familiar with "kernel-trick" based methods.

Comment: @Youem What makes you think that $x,y$ are supposed to be vectors with positive entries?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think it was a condition on the initial question.

Comment: @BenGrossman the edit is accurate, their are indeed positive

Comment: @Norhther That's strange because this requirement is not consistent with the usual definition of a [positive definite kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel).

Comment: @BenGrossmann It seems to me consistent, you take $\mathcal X = \mathbb R^n_{> 0}$.

Comment: @Youem You're right; I'm used to taking the entire vector space as an index set

Comment: @Norhther You might find some of the steps for "building up" a positive kernel [described here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/150964/128205) to be useful

Comment: For instance, it would be sufficient to show that $g(x,y) = \frac{x \cdot y}{\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2}$ defines a positive kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $|x\cdot y|\le\sqrt{\|x\|^2\|y\|^2}\le\frac{\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2}{2}$. Hence $\frac{|x\cdot y|}{\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2}\le\frac12$ and
$$
f(x,y)
=\frac{\frac{x\cdot y}{\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2}}{1-\frac{x\cdot y}{\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2}}
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{x\cdot y}{\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2}\right)^k
$$
can be expressed as an absolutely convergent power series. Therefore
$$
K=\sum_{k=1}^\infty G^{\large\circ k}\circ H^{\large\circ k},
$$
where $G^{\large\circ k}$ and $H^{\large\circ k}$ are the $k$-fold [Hadamard products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of $G=\left(x_i\cdot x_j\right)_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}}=X^\top X$ and
\begin{aligned}
H
&=\left(\frac{1}{\|x_i\|^2+\|x_j\|^2}\right)_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}}\\
&=\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-s(\|x_i\|^2+\|x_j\|^2)}ds\right)_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}}\\
&=\int_0^\infty v(s)v(s)^\top ds
\end{aligned}
respectively, where $v:\mathbb R_{\ge0}\to\mathbb R_{>0}^N$ denotes the vector-valued function $v(s)=(e^{-s\|x_1\|^2},e^{-s\|x_2\|^2},\ldots,e^{-s\|x_N\|^2})^\top$. Since $G$ and $H$ are [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) or sum of Gram matrices, they are positive semidefinite. It follows from [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) that $G^{\large\circ k}\circ H^{\large\circ k}$ is also PSD. Hence $K$, an infinite sum of PSD matrices, is PSD.

Note that we only need each $x_i$ to be a nonzero vector. We don't need them to be entrywise positive.